# Question on a special Derivative

Tags: integration, analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, differential-operators

I have this functional defined from a Hilbert space $H$, $J\colon H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$
J(u)=\frac12 \|u\|^2-\int_0^1(A(su),u) ds
$$ 
where $A\colon H\rightarrow H$ is a potential operator.

[image]

and I want to prove that  $$J'(u)=u-A(u)$$

where $(.,.)$ is the scalair prudact on $H$.

How to do please ?

Edit1: I tried to see 
$\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{J(u+tv)-J(u)}{t}=(u,v)-\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac1t\int_0^1 (A(s(u+tv)),u+tv)-(A(su),u) ds=(u,v)-\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac1t\int_0^1(A(s(u+tv))-A(su),tv)ds$

But i don't know how to continue?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried simply differentiating this (i.e., using the definition of Frechet derivative) and looking what happens?

Comment: yes i tried to do this, i will edit my message

Comment: Is $A$ continuous?

Comment: @gerw why we need that $A$ is continuous

Comment: In that case, you could apply Taylor: $f(u) - f(0) = \int_0^1 (A(s\,u), u) \, \mathrm{d}s$.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, it is trivial. Assume that $A=dB$, according to the definition of a potential operator. Then
$$
\frac{d}{ds}B(su)=dB(su)(u)=\langle A(su),u \rangle.
$$
Therefore
$$
J(u)=\frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2 - B(u),
$$
assuming that $B(0)=0$. As a consequence, $\nabla J(u)=u-A(u)$. Of course we need to justify these manipulations, but I guess that you can add the necessary assumptions on $A$.

Comment: Thank you, we must say that $A$ is continuous ?but why ?

Comment: we can apply this:http://i.stack.imgur.com/sxt2k.jpg we must need that must be $C^1$ ?

Comment: B must be $C^1$ so $A$ must be continuous right ?